# Seasonality for monthly period

Tags: time-series, seasonality, decomposition

The question is simple but I am having a trouble to figure it out.
If I have a monthly data of 5 years how could calculate the seasonality for each month not quarter.

I found this example online and worked out the Trend using excel which is fine but I am still not successful with seasonality.
[image]

Comment: Are you using additive seasonality or multiplicative seasonality? If it is additive, your numbers look OK.

Comment: This is not my work, I found this online and I am trying to find out how they calculated the Seasonal column. And I believe it is additive model